# How to take a snapshot of webview with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, webview, android-webview

I have a webview in Kotlin and is working fine. That I want to achieve is can get a snapshop (preview image) of the website that you are loading. I've search and I only find some deprecated examples in Java code. Someone can point me how to do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution....

Inside of onPageFinished in your WebViewClient put this method and create the snapshot of the website

```
private fun getPreviewWebview(view: WebView): Bitmap{
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, 1500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        view.draw(canvas)

        return bitmap
    }
```